# jQuery Animate - border width and color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I did look through several similar questions over here but couldn't find an answer to mine.

I have jQuery UI set up. And I am trying to set **width** and **color** for the top border of a div using the jQuery animate function.

This code doesn't work in jQuery:

```
$(".newMessageBox").animate({

    borderTopWidth: '1px',
    borderTopColor: '#e5e5e5'

});
```

However if I add the following line to the CSS file:

```
.newMessageBox
{

    border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;

}
```

And then add this to the jQuery

```
$(".newMessageBox").animate({

    borderTopWidth: '1px',

});
```

Then everything is working.

Also if I set up "border-top: 1px solid;" in the CSS and then put "borderTopColor: '#e5e5e5'" in the jQuery animate, then it will work like this too.

Is there a rule that forbids setting two properties for the same element in jQuery animate?

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be your missing borderType perhaps solid in Jquery ? When you do not set solid even it does not work with plain html.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure about the syntax. I tried both "borderTopType: 'solid'" and also "borderType: 'solid'" but it is still not working. 

Perhaps I have a syntax problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try using .css instead.

```
$(".newMessageBox").css({'borderTopWidth', '1px'});
$(".newMessageBox").css({'borderTopColor', '#e5e5e5'});
```